# Allow anonymous submission on a custom element type?

Tags: plugin-development, controller, elementtype, services, models

I have a custom element type that I want to allow anonymous submission from the front-end. I have a solid concept on how the form data is passed but I seem to be missing something.

I have the controller setup like so:

```php
class PluginNameController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @var Allows anonymous access to this controller's actions.
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionSubmit');

    /**
     * Allow public submission of the element type
     */
    public function actionSubmit()
    {
        // require post request for this action
        $this->requirePostRequest();

        $entry = craft()->request->getPost();

        // set the form id from the post request
        $formId = craft()->request->getPost('formId');
        $entry = craft()->request->getPost();

        // if form id is empty, throw exception as we can't continue
        if (!$formId) {
            throw new Exception(Craft::t('The formId is required to submit.'));
        }

        if (craft()->pluginName->publicSubmission($formId, $entry))
        {
            $this->redirectToPostedUrl();
        }
        else
        {
            die('failed submission');
        }
    }
```

My element type has 4 fields that are required and those submit anonymously as expected as I am grabbing them using `getPost`. However, my plugin also utilizes the `getSources` method and each `formId` has a field layout assigned to the custom element type, lets say 'entry'.

Whats causing the trip up is the fact that since this is an element type that utilizes a field layout, I will need to account for the fields based on the `formId`. So when using `getPost` I can namespace the attributes for the element type, but I am trying to find the best way to capture the fields specified in the field layout and save those to the appropriate table..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just to clarify... Is the question about **how to pass data** to a controller? The title implies that you're having trouble submitting anonymously, but it looks like you're doing that part correctly. Where in the script is it failing?

Comment: I need to clean up the question a little more.. Will do that now to make more sense of exactly what I am asking.

Comment: I edited my original question a little bit. The easy part is grabbing the attributes for my element type, but since the et is using a field layout... I'm looking at using `craft()->fields->assembleLayoutFromPost();` and seeing how far that gets me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. The trick was using the following two methods:

- `assembleLayoutFromPost()`
- `setContentFromPost('fields')`

The controller now looks like this:

```php
public function actionSubmit()
{
// require POST
$this->requirePostRequest();

// assume new element type
$elementtype = new PluginName_ElementTypeModel();

// assign the attributes specific to the element type
$elementtype->formId    = craft()->request->getPost('formId');
$elementtype->fieldName1 = craft()->request->getPost('fieldName1');
$elementtype->fieldName2  = craft()->request->getPost('fieldName2');

// if form id does NOT exist
if (!$elementtype->formId)
{
    // @TODO figure out how to return errors/validation
    dd('need a form id');
}
// if form id exists but we can't find it in the system
elseif (craft()->elementtype_forms->getFormById($elementtype->formId) == null)
{
    // @TODO figure out how to return errors/validation
    dd('form does not exist');
}

// setup a new form model
$form = new PluginName_FormModel();

// shared attributes
$form->id = $elementtype->formId;

// set the field layout
$fieldLayout = craft()->fields->assembleLayoutFromPost();
$fieldLayout->type = ElementType::Asset;
$form->setFieldLayout($fieldLayout);

// set content from post with the fields namespace
$elementtype->setContentFromPost('fields');

// Save it
if (craft()->elementtype->save($elementtype))
{
    $this->redirectToPostedUrl($elementtype);
}
else
{
    dd('not saved');
}

}
```

The main difference was on the front-end where I namespaced the fields that were assigned via the field layout, so the template to submit looked like this:

```
<form id="plugin-form"guinname method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="pluginname/submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="pluginname?submit=success">
    <input type="hidden" name="formId" value="1">

<!-- Required Fields -->
<label>Field 1
    <input type="text" name="fieldName1" />
</label>
<label>Last Name
    <input type="text" name="fieldName2" />
</label>
<!-- End Required Fields -->

<!-- My Custom Fields -->
<textarea name="fields[body]" rows="8" cols="40">OMG IT WORKED</textarea>

<button type="submit">Submit Now</button>
</form>
```